# How to reposition my jQuery popup?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've got a popup working with jQuery but it is rendering at the same place as the DIV. I'd like the popup to render in the middle of the page. Is it possible? If yes, then how?

My CSS:

```
.newpopup {
    display:none;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: #eee;
}
```

HTML:

```
 <div class='newpopup'>
</div>
<button>popup</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
function popup() {
    alert('test');
    var popup = $('.newpopup');
    popup.draggable();
    popup.resizable();
    popup.html('<p>Where is pancakes house?</p>');
    popup.show('fast');
}
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('button').click(function(){
     popup();
  });
})
```

Comment: Please post your code fiddle.

Comment: I got this to work now with your help. Now I only need to load the page with JSP content which seems doable. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your popup css `position : absolute` and use `top & left` properties to set your popup position.

```
  .newpopup {
    display:none;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: #eee;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
}
```

**EDIT**

I created a fiddle , [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bZ8NM/) it works perfectly here, check it out.

Comment: I tried it and it didn't work for me. Same result as before, the DIV render where it is written instead of middle of the page. What can be done?

Comment: Thank you for the help. I've made progress today on this question with your help and will continue tomorrow. I can make the DIV appear and disappear and made draggable and positioned so I might just need to add a little more control and the stuff from the page that I actually want to load. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the width and height of the screen, and the box you've created

```
var screen_width = $(document).width();
var screen_height = $(document).height();
var box_width = popup.width();
var box_height = popup.height();
```

You then need to set `position:absolute;` on `.newpopup`. As well as it's `top` and `left` positions

```
var top = (screen_height - box_height) / 2; // you might like to subtract a little to position it slightly higher than half way
var left = (screen_width - box_width) / 2;
popup.css({ 'position': 'absolute', 'top':top, 'left':left });
```

The code can be condensed, but it's easier to understand split up.

**Edit**:
You can add the pop-up box to the start of the page by using `$(body).prepend(popup);`, which will mean it does not get affected by any other element